# Query to compare two column of table 1 with two column of table 2 and update the third column in table 1 as 'y' if the record matches

Tags: sql-server, update, table

I have two tables, Table 1 with column `email` , `number`, `enabled` and Table 2 with column `email`,`number`.
Now i have to compare the records of both the column from Table 1 and Table 2 , If the records matches in both the table then i have to update the column `enabled` as  "Y" in table 1.
Please help me with the query.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be

```
UPDATE t1
SET    t1.enabled = 'Y'
FROM   Table1 t1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   Table2 t2
               WHERE  t1.email = t2.email
                      AND t1.number = t2.number);
```

Or a more concise alternative

```
UPDATE Table1
SET    enabled = 'Y'
FROM   Table2
WHERE  Table1.email = Table2.email
       AND Table1.number = Table2.number;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_1 
SET table_1.fName = t2.FName, table_1.lName = t2.LName, table_1.status = "UPDATED" 
FROM table_1 AS t1 JOIN table_2 AS t2 USING (id) 
WHERE t1.fName!=t2.FName OR t1.lName!=t2.LName
```